# Troubles with console route default values

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm currently trying to get a console route to work with default values

my route is curently configured as:

```php
'console' => array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'fetch-rapportage' => array(
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => 'rapportage --type= [--hid=]',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller'    => 'ZetaRapportage\Controller\Test',
                        'action'        => 'generate',
                        'hid'           => false,
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
),
```

Now when i run the following command

cron rapportage --type virtual

the result comes in as expected

```text
object(Zend\Stdlib\Parameters)#96 (1) {
    ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=>
        array(8) {
            [0] => string(10) "rapportage"
            [1] => string(6) "--type"
            [2] => string(7) "virtual"
            ["type"] => string(7) "virtual"
            ["rapportage"] => bool(true)
            ["controller"] => string(30) "ZetaRapportage\Controller\Test"
            ["action"] => string(8) "generate"
            ["hid"] => bool(false)
        }
}
```

Now when i add the optional flag --hid the result is not as expected

command:

cron rapportage --type virtual --hid 100

output

```text
object(Zend\Stdlib\Parameters)#96 (1) {
    ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=>
        array(10) {
            [0] => string(10) "rapportage"
            [1] => string(6) "--type"
            [2] => string(7) "virtual"
            [3] => string(5) "--hid"
            [4] => string(3) "100"
            ["type"] => string(7) "virtual"
            ["hid"] => bool(false)  <-- expected value 100
            ["rapportage"] => bool(true)
            ["controller"] => string(30) "ZetaRapportage\Controller\Test"
            ["action"] => string(8) "generate"
        }
}
```

So i'm currently in "wait-whut!!!"-mode and cant' figure out why and how?!?!? Someone here that can put a finger on the problem

Answer (score 0):

nevermind it's a bug in ZF2 and it will be fixed in 2.2.0

see
https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/pull/4295

Answer (score 0):

If you want a patch to resolve the issue for you right now while you wait for 2.2.0 to be released, use this (assuming you're running 2.1.5—the latest release):

```
diff --git a/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/Console/Simple.php b/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/Console/Simple.php
index 4105dfb..7c925df 100644
--- a/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/Console/Simple.php
+++ b/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/Console/Simple.php
@@ -797,7 +797,7 @@ class Simple implements RouteInterface
             return null; // there are extraneous params that were not consumed
         }

-        return new RouteMatch(array_replace($matches, $this->defaults));
+        return new RouteMatch(array_replace($this->defaults, $matches));
     }

     /**
```